# Remove genres android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master

Tags: android, android-studio, github, mobile-application, audio-player, android-music-player

I am using "android-UniversalMusicPlayer-master" and I want to remove genres folder which is appearing when the app launch at the e1st time I want to open directly album in previous version on git source.

Answer (score 0):

in Musicprodiver.java file replace this block:

> `if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(mediaId)) {
>   mediaItems.add(createBrowsableMediaItemForRoot(resources));
>   }`

with

```
if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(mediaId)) {
    for (String genre : getGenres()) {
        mediaItems.add(createBrowsableMediaItemForGenre(genre, resources));
    }
}
```

That should display songs by genre on the main activity